# BigCommerce api - How to pull order ID?

Tags: api, bigcommerce

Forgive me ,  Noobie here and to programming and API so I might not have the terminology down correct.

When looking over the BigCommerce API documentation I was trying to figure out how to get the GET orders/id.json to pull a SKU number or the product ID number of the item that was ordered.   I do not see that.   Anyone have a clue?

Maybe I am not using the correct API to get this information?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You will get that info from orders/products. Essentially GET /order/id/products.json

http://developer.bigcommerce.com/docs/api/v2/resources/orders/products